# Mollie split payment after user approval

Tags: payment, mollie

I have this problem, that I want to solve in **Laravel 5** (preferably using **Mollie**).

**PROBLEM**

My platform offers multiple account (free to create, no professionals)
that offer services at various prices. I want a flow where the
customer pays on forehand, and when both parties (customer and service
provider) arrive on scene, they 'accept' the payment and the money
flows to the service provider.

Let's say I want to use serviceA from accountA (User: Jeff, service: painting). I order Jeff for next monday to paint my room, but I need to pay on forehand to ensure Jeff he is really needed here. To make sure Jeff is actually showing up, I want to 'hold' the money somewhere, that is only released when Jeff is on sight and the customer 'accepts' Jeff's presence. When the customer accepts, 95% goes to Jeff, 5% is kept as fee.

**WHAT I HAVE FOUND**

I have contacted Mollie, they told me it is not possible the 'hold/freeze' money in Mollie or in the cloud.. Blablacar (for example) let's users pay to blablacar, and they on their turn pay back the money when the user is delivered (minus a small fee). Only problem I see here is that I want my platform to be stand-alone. When both the customer and the service provider click 'accept' the money transfer should happen automatically. Is that even possible? Payments always required some sort of password or identification.

Is there an obvious other (easy) method I am missing? First time building a platform with payments, so I have no experience with any service whatsoever..

Thanks for your expertise and help.

Comment: You don't mention it as an option, but for completeness sake it's good to know that collecting the money yourself and paying it through to the different parties is probably not an option because you would need a licence from [supervisors like DNB](https://www.dnb.nl/en/supervision/innovationhub/index.jsp).

Comment: What you could do, is let the customer pay a small amount in advance to prove they're the owner of the bank account or credit card. This would create a mandate in the Mollie API. Using this mandate you can create a [background (recurring) payment](https://mollie.com/nl/docs/recurring) using credit card or SEPA direct debit when both parties accept. However, it can't be guaranteed that this background payment will succeed. So for your use case this might be unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your view on this, but it doesn't seem like the way to go for me. I only need a one-off payment, and some sort of control over the exact time the money flows from A to B (and a small fee to C).